# Display each contents of UI-Grid in tab pane

Tags: angularjs, mean

I have an requiremet where there is a ui-grid which contains list of all users with a hyperlink cell on click of a user in Grid it should display the detailed view of User in a tab pane for SPA project please help me

Comment: on click of the cell try to get the data by creating a ng-click function pass $event as a parameter and in js get the data and assign it to the ng-model  of the field in tab pane that's it

Comment: Do u have a plunker or some sample code for the same..Please help

Comment: first create a plunker with UI grid and Tab pane and give the link will give a try on that